# What professional helps teach parents how to parent?

Tags: parents, psychology

What's the name given to the person that teaches parents how to parent?

Dog trainers usually don't only teach dogs tricks. They show the owners, how they can teach the dog things, how they can master challenging situations, and how dog owners can communicate better with their dogs in general. In this way, they are more dog-owner-trainers than dog trainers.  I am looking for the parent version of this: someone who can teach a parent how to parent.

Comment: Fixed the title and question slightly; I’m not sure the dog training bit is relevant but it doesn’t detract when it’s put second I think.

Comment: Intuition and experiment plus a lot of advice from ppl who have kids I.e ur siblings, parents, in laws (not a fan) n other.

Comment: I really like this question because this world goes like "drive a car? do a job? have any response? you need a qualification!". But for kids? "Congratulation to your child, now go and see ...".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mother in law?

More seriously, a [parent coach](https://www.verywellfamily.com/what-is-a-parenting-coach-1094737) is what you’re looking for.  There are also more specific roles, such as a lactation consultant, who would help with specific things, but parent coach is someone who would help you be a better parent and teach you skills that you might not have learned in normal life.

Comment: Sad thing is the people who need a coach most would not want one, and probably could not afford one if they wanted one.

Answer (score 5):

Child psychologists and child development experts are among the professionals who teach parenting skills.

**EXAMPLES:**
Coursera class ["Everyday Parenting: The ABCs of Child Rearing"](https://www.coursera.org/learn/everyday-parenting) is taught by [Alan E. Kazdin](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/alan-kazdin), PhD, ABPP Sterling Professor of Psychology and Child Psychiatry at Yale University.
Coursera class ["Motivating Gen Z Learners: What Parents and Teachers Need to Know"](https://www.coursera.org/learn/motivate-genz-learners) is taught by [Stefanie Chye](https://www.coursera.org/instructor/%7E41824246), Assistant Professor with Psychology and Child & Human Development Academic Group, National Institute of Education, Nanyang Technological University.